# HAProxy agent - all ready but the backend is considered down

Tags: haproxy

We have 4 backends, with an agent-check reporting "ready 68%" (the number changes, of course) for each 4. But for some reason, HAProxy sees them as UP but soft stopped. So each line is dark blue in the stats page, all of them are up, but the general backend line says down.

What is required for that to actually work ? Does it need something like "ready up 68%" ? It's unclear, we tried a few things but I cannot get haproxy to consider them usable, for some reason.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, just figured it out. You just need to add a weight to each server manually, I guess trying to set a 50% weight if you haven't specified any numbers doesn't make any sense.
I added a weight 100 to each server, and it seems all good now !

Answer (score 0):

Your right it's not that clear :-).

Its designed so that the agent will only override the health status of HAProxy if you explicitly ask it to. So if the agent had previously set a DRAIN mode then HAproxy needs an explicit command to re-activate the server.

When you restart the [Windows Feedback Agent](https://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/open-source-windows-service-for-reporting-server-load-back-to-haproxy-load-balancer-feedback-agent/) (or change health mode) it automatically sends "up ready X%" (for 10 seconds or so...)
Then defaults back to "X%" for normal operation.

You'll need to replicate something like that if you are using Linux.

Comment: Oh, so you actually need up and ready at the same time. Is that okay to just have them all the time then ?

Comment: Well tried that, doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: Not sure if that was clear, but each individual backend server is considered UP, but the whole backend block is considered DOWN anyway. It looks like haproxy has the servers in soft down mode for some reason, but the agent never sent that order : it's not even implemented. I check with tcpdump, haproxy is getting "up ready X%" from each agent, and it is parsing the "up" properly according to the last_msg field in the csv stats. No idea why it's still considering it soft down